# How to continue after exception occurred in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    static string SomeMethodThatMightThrow(string s)
    {
        if (s[4] == 'C')
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        return @"C:\newFolder\" + s;

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string[] files = { "fileA.txt", "B.txC", "fileC.txt","fileD.txt" };

    var exceptionDemoQuery =
        from file in files
        let n = SomeMethodThatMightThrow(file)
        select n;
    try
    {
        foreach (var item in exceptionDemoQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", item);
        }
    }

    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Output is

Processing C:\newFolder\fileA.txt

Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

But i need the Output as:

Processing C:\newFolder\fileA.txt

Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Processing C:\newFolder\fileD.txt

Please help in this.............

Comment: This is tomorrow's homework, I assume?

Comment: I'm surprised at the upvote.  I'd have guessed this was pretty clearly in the realm of "an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended question". http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Answer (score 3):

Perform `SomeMethodThatMightThrow` wrapped in a `try/catch` within the `foreach` .

Example:

```
var exceptionDemoQuery =
    from file in files
    select file;

foreach (var item in exceptionDemoQuery)
{
  try
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", item);
    var n = SomeMethodThatMightThrow(item);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: correct solution indeed but perhaps not the one that fits into OP's program structure ;-)

Comment: @VinayC: Not so, i'll expand.

Comment: I commented based on assumption that OP will have for each loop at some different location and will get enumerable structure as input (where SomeMethodThatMightThrow can actual have different pluggable implementation). But really, I might be imagining too much - solution that you have sighted may work for OP.

Answer (score 0):

static string SomeMethodThatMightThrow(string s)
        {
           try
           {
               if (s[4] == 'C')
                   throw new InvalidOperationException();
                return @"C:\newFolder\" + s;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
               return e.Message;
             }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                  return "other error";
             }

```
    }   
    static void Main(string[] args)   
    {   
       string[] files = { "fileA.txt", "B.txC", "fileC.txt","fileD.txt" };   

    var exceptionDemoQuery =   
        from file in files   
        let n = SomeMethodThatMightThrow(file)   
        select n;   

        foreach (var item in exceptionDemoQuery)   
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", item);   
        }   



    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");   
    Console.ReadKey();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I guess your result from operation should contain both actual result and exception (in case that happens) - for example,

```
static Func<string, Tuple<string, Exception>> OperationWrapper(Func<string, string> op)
{ 
   return s => { 
       try
       { 
          return Tuple.Create<string, Exception>(op(s), null);
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
          return Tuple.Create<string, Exception>(null, ex);
       }
   };
}

// goes rest of the code except changes shown below
...

var wrapper = OperationWrapper(SomeMethodThatMightThrow);
var exceptionDemoQuery =
        from file in files
        let n = wrapper(file)
        select n;

        foreach (var item in exceptionDemoQuery)
        {
            if (item.Item2 == null)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", item.Item1);
            }
            else
            { 
                 // we have exception
                 Console.WriteLine(item.Item2.Message); 
            }
        }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
```

I have use `OperationWrapper` assuming that you may have many such functions otherwise you may change the actual function itself.